# Elency Solutions CSV Library Error C#

Tags: c#, csv, load, save, helper

I am using the elency solutions CSV library for C# to save and load some data from a file.

My code saves and loads correctly, but when I load and then try to save an error occurs, saying that another process is using the file.

The load method is this:

```
private void loadfile(string name)
{
    int key = 696969;
    CsvReader read = new CsvReader("data.csv");

    try
    {
        do
        {
            read.ReadNextRecord();
        } while (name != read.Fields[0]);
        int decAgain = int.Parse(read.Fields[1], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); //convert to int
        int dec = decAgain ^ key;
        MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
    }
        read = null;

}
```

As you can see, I am sort of disposing the "read" object.

Here is the save method:

```
private void savefile(string encrypted, string name)
{
    CsvFile file = new CsvFile();
    CsvRecord rec = new CsvRecord();
    CsvWriter write = new CsvWriter();

    rec.Fields.Add(name);
    rec.Fields.Add(encrypted);

    file.Records.Add(rec);
    write.AppendCsv(file, "data.csv");

    file = null;
    rec = null;
    write = null;

}
```

It always gets stuck on append csv. 
I do understand the problem. The reader is not being closed successfully. How can I correctly close the file?

NB: I have tried `read.Dispose()` but it is not working.

Can you please help me out?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use using to automatically dispose object. It may solve your issue.

```
private void savefile(string encrypted, string name)
{
    using(CsvFile file = new CsvFile())
    {
        using(CsvRecord rec = new CsvRecord())
        {
            using(CsvWriter write = new CsvWriter())
            {

                rec.Fields.Add(name);
                rec.Fields.Add(encrypted);

                file.Records.Add(rec);
                write.AppendCsv(file, "data.csv");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: although the error was starting from the loading i applied your theory on the loading part and it seems to have solved my issue thanks!!